# What does this Typescript syntax mean

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export declare type SomeType = {
   [key: string] : string
};
```

What exactly does this syntax mean? We are exporting a custom type alias called SomeType that is an object that has a property that is called ____ and is of value ____ ?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561980/what-does-declare-in-export-declare-type-xyz-mean-vs-export-type-xyz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that an object of type `SomeType` can only have string properties with string values:

Example:

```js
// Valid
{

    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'

},

// Invalid
{

    firstName: 'John',
    age: 10

}
```

This syntax is called [Index Signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures).

Comment: So this ``[key: string] : string`` is not a single property? What is the thing that is happening here called? ( the fact that an array is declared and it gets stretched out to represent the properties of the object) ?

Comment: No, is not a single property. It is called Index Signature. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a key/value structure. The key is a string and the value is a string

```
SomeType = {
   'a-string-key' : 'a-string-value'
};
```

Comment: Yes, but how does ``[key: string] : string`` translate to `` { property1: string; property2: string... etc} ``

Comment: let say you have this structure

{ 
name: 'adam',  // OK
name2: 'danny' // OK
name3: 123      // Not Ok
}

Comment: Yes i get that. But how does this work and what is it called? The fact that instead of writing this: ``SomeType = { property1: string; property2: string, property3: string}`` i can just write ``SomeType = { [key : string] : string}``

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Typescript is a static typed version of javascript. In this case, we have a type called `SomeType` which is an Object. And we are also mentioning the object's `key` and `value` type in this manner - `[key: string]: string`.

In your case, `SomeType` will only accept a `key` of string and `value` of string. Else, It will throw a type error.

Eg: `{ "name": "user"}` is valid and `{"name" : 10 }` is invalid.